# vertical scroll should be stop at certain limit

Tags: css, scroll

Please see this link:
http://touche.softquanta.org/

Can I stop vertical scroller on end of orange footer boundry.

Answer (score 0):

if that's your footer then just set it as

```
#footer{position:absolute; bottom:0;}
```